# query oracle database through a java applet

Tags: java, oracle, applet

Actually Iam writing a plugin for an java app that comes in two flavours 1.)as executable and 2.) can be launched from a webpage as an applet.

At some point I needed a custom form that displays various data from an oracle database. I build that form and the class that does the jdbc query needed.

Now when it comes to the executable the form pops up correctly with the expected results, but when I try to call it from the applet it launches with all fields empty and no error whats so ever.

The only thing I can think of is that due to the asychronous nature of the web, the form pops up before the query returns the result.

If that is true, is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you just catch exceptions and therefore do not see them. Or just do not know where to search for them. Did you open applet console? I believe that you will find some exception there.

Applet is not different from application. Applet just has security restrictions. It cannot perform TCP connection to server other than one it was downloaded from. And important: the security check is pretty stupid. It is based on string comparison. It just compares host names of applet base and the host name of host where you want to connect. If for example your host name is myhost.mycompany.com and its IP is 200.201.202.203 you have to use either DNS name or IP address in both places even if ping of DNS name returns your IP adderess. Check this and I hope everything will work.

BTW, do you probably know that you are using "old", "obsolete" design? This is the beginning of 90s design. People switched to N-tier architecture ~12 years ago, so, to improve your solution you should implement DB access on server side and talk to server via some kind of protocol, e.g. rest API.

Comment: Iam aware that iam using an old design but the client bought this app nearly a decade ago and still wishes to use it with some modifications. Plus iam not supposed to have access to the source code. So in any case who Am I to argue. thanks though, your answer gave me a few clues and a few things to test. The Java console doesnt return any relative exceptions.